# underlying text in string in android

Tags: android

this is my string.xml

```
<string name="terms_condition"> Accept the <u>Terms &amp; Conditions</u></string>
```

this is mytextview

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/terms_condition"
        android:padding="25dp"
        />



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

i am using this code for display underline text but there is no space between two string. how keep space between two text and how to reduce underline? in below screen you can see underline problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<string name="terms_condition"> Accept the\n<u>Terms &amp; Conditions</u></string>`. I think this should work.

Comment: and i dont want it in next line i want in same line but bit space

Comment: If you want space - just insert `\t` in the place where you want it to be (can be used many times in a row: `\t\t\t`)

Comment: I mean, inside `<string>` definition in `strings.xml` file

Comment: Welcome:)
Don't forget to mark an answer as useful if it was